# Ordered interface is not taken into account for @ControllerAdvice components

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

From Spring Javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html both `Ordered` interface and `@Order` annotation should be supported for `@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes. But this does not work for my exception handler:

```java
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class MyExceptionHandler implements Ordered {...}
```

After looking into [ControllerAdviceBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/ControllerAdviceBean.java) source code and during debug I see that `Ordered` is not considered in my case:

```java
private ControllerAdviceBean(Object bean, @Nullable BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.bean = bean;
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    Class<?> beanType;

    if (bean instanceof String) {
        String beanName = (String) bean;
        Assert.hasText(beanName, "Bean name must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(beanFactory, "BeanFactory must not be null");
        if (!beanFactory.containsBean(beanName)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("BeanFactory [" + beanFactory +
                    "] does not contain specified controller advice bean '" + beanName + "'");
        }
        beanType = this.beanFactory.getType(beanName);
        // only this code is executed !!!
        // this uses only @Order annotation 
        this.order = initOrderFromBeanType(beanType); 
    }
    else {
        // dead code??? only String arguments are passed to this constructor by Spring
        Assert.notNull(bean, "Bean must not be null");
        beanType = bean.getClass();
        // this uses Ordered and @Order annotation
        this.order = initOrderFromBean(bean);  
    }
    ...
}
```

See also `ControllerAdviceBean.findAnnotatedBeans()` how annotated beans are found:

```java
public static List<ControllerAdviceBean> findAnnotatedBeans(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    List<ControllerAdviceBean> beans = new ArrayList<ControllerAdviceBean>();
    for (String name : BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(applicationContext, Object.class)) {
        if (applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(name, ControllerAdvice.class) != null) {
            beans.add(new ControllerAdviceBean(name, applicationContext)); // String passed first argument
        }
    }

    return beans;
}
```

Am I missing something about `@ControllerAdvice`? Or this is a bug?

Comment: what are your expectations?

Comment: It would be great to fix this and support for `Ordered`. If it's too complicated then at least we should update docs.

Comment: See related Spring GitHub issue for the latest details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23163